# Shopify API in PHP using GuzzleHttp array of objects

Tags: laravel, shopify, guzzle

I am currently attempting to update a bunch of products via the Shopify API, however, when I am sending the request, the product is created, however, it appears to be ignoring things where it is an array or arrays (for example, images or variants).

This is my Shopify Helper class that I am using for all requests.

```
class Shopify {

    protected $api_key;
    protected $password;
    protected $url;
    protected $host;
    protected $secret;
    protected $client;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->api_key = env('SHOPIFY_API_KEY');
        $this->password = env('SHOPIFY_API_PASSWORD');
        $this->secret = env('SHOPIFY_API_SHARED_SECRET');
        $this->host = env('SHOPIFY_API_HOST');

        $this->url = "https://{$this->api_key}:{$this->password}@{$this->host}";
        $this->client = new Client();
    }

    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        $method = strtoupper($method);
        $allowedMethods = ['POST','GET','PUT','DELETE'];

        if(!in_array($method,$allowedMethods)){
            throw new InvalidMethodRequestException();
        }
        return $this->request($method,trim($args[0]),$args[1] ?? []);
    }

    protected function request(string $method, string $uri, array $payload)
    {
        $response = $this->client->request(
            $method,
            "{$this->url}{$uri}",
            [
                'form_params' => $payload
            ]
        );

        return json_decode($response->getBody());
    }

}
```

Here is an example of me using this client to create a product with a variant:

```
$shopify = new Shopify();

$result = $shopify->post('/admin/api/2020-10/products.json', [
    'product' => [
        'title' => $product->title,
        'body_html' => $product->body_text,
        "variants" => [
            [ "sku" => $product->sku, "price" => 20.00 ]
        ]
    ]
]);
```

As I mentioned above, the product is created in Shopify, but is missing anything where the data is an array of arrays. Could this be todo with the way GuzzleHttp encodes the data? How can get this data in a format that Shopify needs?

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good. The variants output maybe need some conversion to json format.

As you can see here, the expected post request:

```
 "variants": [
  {
    "option1": "First",
    "price": "10.00",
    "sku": "123"
  },
```

I would try to dump the post variable before the request and see what is wrong.

I made some successfull code with laravel in the past using  Facades, and worked. But it took me some time to make it as shopify needs.

PS: I'm using tokens here https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/17056443-how-to-generate-a-shopify-api-token

See:

```
//my endpoint, in your case '/admin/api/2020-10/products.json
$endpoint = config('endpoint');
//registered as a token.

$token = config('token');

$postFields = 'product' => [
    'title' => $product->title,
    'body_html' => $product->body_text,
    "variants" => [
        [ "sku" => $product->sku, "price" => 20.00 ]
    ]
];
//in case of any problems, you can uncomment this line and inspect your request.
//json_encode will help with this
//dd(json_encode($postFields));
return Http::withHeaders([
  "content-type" => "application/json",
  "Authorization" => "Bearer " . $token
])->post($endpoint, $postFields)->json();
```

Comment: Using the Http::withHeaders bit seemed to work, I'm guessing that it could either be the content type header or perhaps Laravel's Http's (although a wrapper for Guzzle) does some additional processing or formatting. Thanks a bunch for this, hours of headache now gone :)